# Why does the same address return different values?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to debug code that - from my understanding - is equivalent to the following...

```
printf("outside function: %d %d\n", node->ns, node->ns[0]);
function(node->ns);
void function(int *ns) {
     printf("inside function: %d %d\n", ns, ns[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
outside function: 11532860 1
inside function: 11532860 11532872
```

Is this expected, or must my interpretation of the code be incorrect? Something fishy with that "11532872".

### Update

I solved it! The problem was in the creation of the node structure.

Original version, where `function()` (from the snippet above) ==  `_contains()`:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    char *word;
    int lines;
    int *line_numbers;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode *allocate_tree_node(void) {
    return (TreeNode *) malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
}

TreeNode *create_tree_node(char *word, int line) {
    int line_numbers[MAX_LINES_PER_WORD]; // <--- the problem
    TreeNode *node = allocate_tree_node();
    node->line_numbers = line_numbers; // <--- the problem
    *node->line_numbers = line;
    node->lines = 1;
    node->word = duplicate_string(word);
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

int _contains(int *ns, int n, int size) {
    int i;
    printf("contains: %d %d %d\n", ns, ns[0], *ns);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("line: %d, index: %d, val: %d\n", n, i, ns[i]);
        if (ns[i] == n) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

TreeNode *add_tree(TreeNode *node, char *word, int line) {
    int comparison;

    if (node == NULL) {
        return create_tree_node(word, line);
    }

    comparison = strcmp(word, node->word);
    if (comparison == 0 && !_contains(node->line_numbers, line, node->lines)) {
        printf("not contains: %d %d\n", node->line_numbers, node->line_numbers[0]);
        node->line_numbers[node->lines] = line;
        node->lines++;
    }
    else if (comparison < 0) {
        node->left = add_tree(node->left, word, line);
    }
    else {
        node->right = add_tree(node->right, word, line);
    }

    return node;
}
```

Fixed version, using malloc instead of array assignment:

```
TreeNode *create_tree_node(char *word, int line) {
    TreeNode *node = allocate_tree_node();
    node->line_numbers = malloc(MAX_LINES_PER_WORD * (sizeof node->line_numbers));
    *node->line_numbers = line;
    node->lines = 1;
    node->word = duplicate_string(word);
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

The output is now correct. Would someone mind explaining what happened?

(The code is based on K&R chapter 6, exercise 3).

Comment: What is `node` in this case?

Comment: not 100% sure. I think by calling function(node->ns) you just pass a copy of the node->ns pointer. The new pointer will be placed on the stack and gains it own address.

Comment: Please use `"%p"`, not `"%d"`, to print pointers.

Comment: you're going to have to provide more information because I tried recreating your program and had no issues, http://ideone.com/yop8px

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll add extra code.

Comment: I actually managed to figure out what was causing the problem. Still not sure *why* it was causing the problem, so the green tick goes to whoever can explain it to me!

Comment: If you solved this yourself, you should answer your own question rather than update the question.

Comment: I would, but I can't explain why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original form of your question had two problems:

1. The code was incomplete.
2. You were using (still are) `%d` for a pointer.

Because of that, it's hard to know for sure what was wrong.  Your subsequent edit,

> Fixed version, using malloc instead

suggests a reasonable possibility: that you were using the an automatic array outside its scope.  That's known in C as *undefined behavior*, and if that's what was going on, strange values are not surprising.

Further evidence is here:

```
TreeNode *create_tree_node(char *word, int line) {
    int line_numbers[MAX_LINES_PER_WORD]; // <--- the problem
    TreeNode *node = allocate_tree_node();
    node->line_numbers = line_numbers; // <--- the problem
    *node->line_numbers = line;
    node->lines = 1;
    node->word = duplicate_string(word);
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

`node->line_numbers` is a pointer, and the local variable `line_numbers` has what's known as `automatic` storage.  (C programmers often refer to automatic variables as being "on the stack", which they sometimes are, but "the stack" is not a C concept.)  Like all variables, automatic variables are defined only within their scope.  If you take the address of one, and try to use that address outside the variable's scope, the behavior is undefined, and almost always not what you want.

That's the soup you step in when you do this:

```
int line_numbers[MAX_LINES_PER_WORD];
node->line_numbers = line_numbers;
...
return node;
```

As you know, in C the name of an array is its address.  Your array is `line_numbers`.  You assign its address to a pointer, `node->line_numbers`.
Once `create_tree_node` returns, the automatic variable local to `create_tree_node`, i.e. `line_numbers` goes out of scope.  The compiler at that point is free to re-use the storage it had allocated to to the variable.  Yes, you still have its address in `node`, but sooner than later the compiler is apt to use that space for something else.  Sure enough, when you print out the value at that address, you're apt to find something other than what you put there.

Comment: Perfect, I understand now. I didn't post all the code because there was a lot of fluff in the program that I didn't think was needed to demonstrate the problem. Thanks!